# You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to ReactJS. On Initial Load of Page, I want to check if the `state` is null, then I want to redirect to another `login Page`

Here's the Component Code:

```
export default function Addblousesalwar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  console.log(state)   //null
  if(state === null || state === undefined){
    navigate("/login")
  }
```

But It shows error:

```
You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.
```

I tried via useEffect also. But the useEffect doesn't get executed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, []);



useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, []);
```

I tried this also

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, [state]);
```

This useeffect also not triggering
Please Help me with some solutions

Comment: Use `console.log(state)` to debug what it is

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is ***guaranteed*** to trigger the callback *at least* once when the component mounts. What isn't working, the navigation? Check the `state` value in the effect callback to see why the condition is not met. Also, `Addblousesalwar` doesn't appear to be a React function component or custom hook so it can't use React hooks anyway.

Comment: state is `null`

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this navigation/mounting issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you should really provide a codesandbox or at least more code.

That being said, I'm gonna guess that 'state' is not undefined nor is it null, it's an [] (that's usually what it's defaulted to `const [state, setState] = useState([])` )
and that's why you think it's not working.

try

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!state.length){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use useEffect after all asynchronous function, here the example:

```
const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('user-info');
    
async function signUp() 
{
    let item = {name, password, email};
    console.warn(item);
    let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register",{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "content-type": 'application/json',
                "Accept": 'application/json'}
        })
    result  = await result.json();
    console.warn('result', result);
    localStorage.setItem("user-info",JSON.stringify(result));
    navigate("/add");
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo){
     navigate("/add")   
    }
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(state == null || state == undefined){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, [state, navigate]);

there is
```

Comment: `state == null || state == undefined` is redundant. Just `== null` will do.

Answer (score -1):

```
export default function Addblousesalwar() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { state } = useLocation();

    //I used useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect and the below turned into warning instead of an error

    //You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.

     useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, []);
 }
```

Comment: to me this changes the url in the bar but renders the component Addblousesalwar

Answer (score -3):

Try adding "state" and "navigate" to your "useEffect" dependencies. Maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).