# Page back to login call navigate() when call direct link React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am new to ReactJS. On Initial Load of Page, I want to check if the state is null, then I want to redirect to another login Page

Here's the Component Code:

```
export default function Addblousesalwar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  console.log(state)   //null
  if(state === null || state === undefined){
    navigate("/login")
  }
```

But It shows error:

You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.
I tried via useEffect also. But the useEffect doesn't get executed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }, []);



useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }, []);
```

I tried this also

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null || state === undefined){
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }, [state]);
```

This useeffect also not triggering Please Help me with some solutions

Comment: In a comment you mentioned that you get "**TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userName' of 'state' as it is null**". So the error seems to be at another location which is not included in the code you posted.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yes It's  from other location. Sometimes I get the value as null from other location. So I want to handle that error. If it was null, i want to redirect to login Page....

Comment: if you fix that error, of the destructuring, the `useEffect` will execute and the navigation will occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165718/you-should-call-navigate-in-a-react-useeffect-not-when-your-component-is-fi)

Answer (score -1):

The state may contain empty object `{}`. Try checking condition for empty object too

```
useEffect(() => {
if(state === null || state === undefined || state === {}){
  navigate("/")
}
}, [state]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userName' of 'state' as it is null.

Comment: `state === {}` will always return `false`.

Comment: @somaiyappan I tried your code and it is redirecting to `login` when `state` is `null`.